# Como ocultar exibe.php do link (url amigável)

Tags: htaccess, url, url-amigável

Tudo bem?
Por favor, preciso de ajuda...

Atualmente, o meu site apresenta links da seguinte forma: [https://site.com/pagina/noticia/2019/ciencia-e-saude/exibe.php?link=página-do-leitor-é-maneira](https://site.com/pagina/noticia/2019/ciencia-e-saude/exibe.php?link=p%C3%A1gina-do-leitor-%C3%A9-maneira)

Na pasta do "ciencia-e-saude", eu tenho um arquivo `exibe.php` que serve pra exibir o conteúdo de determinado link.

Veja como tá o index que "puxa esse arquivo":

```
<a class="post-img" href="exibe.php?link=<?php echo $ciencia_e_saude['link'];?>"
```

Queria poder fazer uma URL amigável que "ocultasse" o "exibe.php" da página...

Atualmente, esse é o meu "**.htacess**":

```
<files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    satisfy all
</files>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
    RewriteRule ^([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)$ /exibe?link=


<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

Vocês podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

O ideal é que para seu site ficar dinâmico, você não tenha "pastas" das categorias.
Veja bem, o ideal é que você tenha apenas o arquivo exibe.php na sua raiz, e receba todos os parâmetros da URL neste arquivo.
Um exemplo da sua URL "não amigável" seria assim:
`https://site.com/pagina/exibe.php?tipo=noticia&ano=2019&categoria=ciencia-e-saude&link=página-do-leitor-é-maneira`

Perceba que cada parâmetro dessa url acima representará no final uma "/" na sua URL.
Com o modelo acima, sua regra de reescrita ficará assim:

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /pagina/exibe.php?tipo=$1&ano=$2&categoria=$3&link=$4 [L]`

No seu arquivo exibe.php, você consegue acessar cada um desses parâmetros através da variável $_GET:
`$ano = $_GET['ano']`

`$categoria = $_GET['categoria']`

Uma outra alternativa seria você usar alguma lib que permita a criação de rotas, tipo [essa](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter)